# Chosen JS Drop-down list not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

I have three drop-down lists: Region, location, and person. You can select the region, which filters the locations, and then select a location, which filters the people from there. If you select a person first, then it will select their Region and location. If you then click to view the persons drop-down list, you will only see the people at that location. The issue appeared when I added Chosen.js to make the people drop down list searchable. When I added it, the people drop down list is no longer filtering.

Region DDL:

```
                <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.Label("Region", new {@class="control-label", @for="region"})
                <select name="region" id="region" class="form-control input-md">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    @foreach (var elem in Model.Regions)
                    {
                        if (Model.Person != null){
                            if (Model.Person.region.Equals(elem.Name))
                            {
                                <option value="@elem.Name" selected="selected">@elem.Name</option>
                            } else {
                                <option value="@elem.Name">@elem.Name</option>
                            }
                        } else {
                            <option value="@elem.Name">@elem.Name</option>
                        }

                    }
                </select>
            </div>
```

Location DDL:

```
                <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.Label("Location", new {@class="control-label", @for="location"})
                <select name="location" id="location" class="form-control input-md">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    @foreach (var elem in Model.Locations)
                    {
                        if (Model.Person != null){
                            if (Model.Person.location.Equals(elem.Name))
                            {
                                <option data-regionid="@elem.Region" value="@elem.Name" selected="selected" >@elem.Name</option>
                            } else {
                                <option data-regionid="@elem.Region" value="@elem.Name">@elem.Name</option>
                            }
                        } else {
                                <option data-regionid="@elem.Region" value="@elem.Name">@elem.Name</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
```

Person DDL:

```
                <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.Label("Person", new {@class="control-label", @for="person"})
                <select name="person" id="person" class="form-control input-md chosen-select">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    @foreach (var elem in Model.Person)
                    {
                        if (Model.PersonId.Equals(elem.id)){
                            <option data-regionid="@elem.region" data-locationid="@elem.location" value="@elem.id" selected="selected">@elem.name (@elem.location)</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
```

Here is the javascript that filters that drop downs:

```
    locations = $("#location > option").clone();
persons = $("#person > option").clone();


$("#region").change(function () {
    if ($("#region").val().length != 0) {
        filterDropDown("#location", locations, "regionid", $("#region").val());
        filterDropDown("#person", persons, "regionid", $("#region").val());
    } else {
        $("#location").html(locations.clone());
        $("#person").html(persons.clone());

        $("#location").val("");
        $("#person").val("");
    }
});

function resetDropVals(list) {
    $(list).each(function (index, item) {
        $(item).removeAttr("selected");
    });
}

$("#location").change(function () {
    if ($("#location").val().length > 0) {
        if ($("#region").val().length == 0) {
            var selectedLocation = $("#location").val();

            filterParent("#region", "#location", "regionid");
            filterDropDown("#location", locations, "regionid", $("#region").val());

            $("#location").val(selectedLocation);
        }
        filterDropDown("#person", persons, "locationid", $("#location").val());
    } else {
        if ($("#region").val().length > 0) {
            filterDropDown("#person", persons, "regionid", $("#region").val());
        } else {
            $("#person").html(persons.clone());
            $("#person").val("");
        }
    }

});

function filterParent(parentdd, childdd, dataName) {
    if ($(parentdd).val().length == 0) {
        $(parentdd + " option").each(function (index, item) {
            if ($(item).val() == $(childdd + " option:selected").data(dataName)) {
                $(parentdd).val($(item).val());
            }
        });
    }
}

$("#person").change(function () {
    if ($("#person").val().length > 0) {
        var selectedPerson = $("#person").val();

        filterParent("#location", "#person", "locationid");
        filterDropDown("#person", persons, "locationid", $("#location").val());

        var selectedLocation = $("#location").val();

        filterParent("#region", "#location", "regionid");
        filterDropDown("#location", locations, "regionid", $("#region").val());

        $("#person").val(selectedPerson);
        $("#location").val(selectedLocation);
    }
});


function filterDropDown(ddName, optionList, dataName, groupVal) {
    $(ddName).html("");
    $(ddName).append("<option></option");
    $(optionList).each(function (index, item) {
        if ($(item).data(dataName) == groupVal) {
            $(ddName).append($(item).clone());
        }
    });
}

});
```

Any idea to why chosen would be stopping the drop-down list from filtering when the values in the other lists are selected? I just don't see how it could be interfering. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using chosen, the drop down lists need to be manually updated after the filter events are called:

```
$(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
```